# Linear combination of matrix functions is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

We are given two smooth $m \times m$ matrix functions $F_1, F_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$. We are also given bounded open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$, such that $F_i$ is non-singular (invertible) in a slightly larger open set containing $\overline{U_i}$ for $i = 1, 2$. Is there a linear combination $C = a_1F_1 + a_2F_2$ for some $a_1, a_2\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $C$ is invertible on $U_1 \cup U_2$?

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ and $A$ are any matrix then $det(M-tA)$ is a polynomial in $t$. If in addition $M$ is invertible, this polynomial is non zero hence has only finitely many zeroes. So $M-tA$ is invertible for all but finitely $t$. Moreover the $t$ making this determinant vanish locally depends continously on $M$ and $A$ (local inversion theorem).

Therefore for all $x \in U_1$ we can find an open neighborhood$N_x$ of $x$ and a real $M_x$ such that for $t>M_x$, $F_1+tF_2$ is invertible on $N_x$.

Now the closure of $U_1$ is closed and bounded so we can cover it by a finite number of neighborhoods of the form $N_{x_i}$. Taking $t$ larger than the maximum of the corresponding $M_{x_i}$ we ensure that $F_1+tF_2$ is invertible on $U_1$.

Next we do an analogous trick on $U_2$ and we get that for $t$ sufficiently large, $F_1+tF_2$ is invertible.

Comment: Nice proof, thanks! Maybe to be slightly careful, if $F_2$ is not invertible on $U_1$, then the degree of $\det(F_1 + tF_2)$ could vary as polynomial in $t$ and so does the number of zeros. But I guess the largest zero is still uniformly bounded by norms of $F_1$ and $F_2$ on $U_1$, so this doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure anymore the claim is true. Consider $m = n = 1$ and $U_1 = (-2, -\frac{1}{4})$, $U_2 = (-\frac{3}{4}, 1)$, with $F_1 = x$ and $F_2 = x + 1$. We can wlog assume that $a_1 = 1$, so $C = x + t(x + 1)$. But $C = 0$ is the same as $t = -\frac{x}{x + 1}$. In the proximity of $x = -1$, we will have $C = 0$ for some $x$. So the claim is not true in the real case even for scalars. The problem is that the set of $t$ in your first paragraph making the determinant vanish can be discontinuous if $M$ is degenerate.

Comment: You're right my proof is faulty. On the other hand, if $F_1(x)=x$ and $F_2(x)=x-1$ then just take $F_1 - F_2$ so at least the claim holds in this case... I'll think about it again.

Comment: Ok the claim is indeed wrong, at least if we restrict $a_1, a_2$ to be real. Indeed, consider $F_1(t)=\cos(t)$ and $F_2(t) = \sin(t)$ and $U_i$ conveniently chosen to avoid the zeroes of $F_i$. Then any real linear combination of those still have a zero.